# Can you use the Filter() function on a list to create a new list from a larger list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, finance

I would be using the list and filter functions to create a new list containing only the odd length stock tickers. I have used `lambda` before doing something similar with numbers but can't seem to translate it to words. My code is below..

```
list1 = ["GOOGL", "IBM", "AAPL", "FB", "M", "WMT"]

list(filter(lambda item: item[0] == "odd", list1))
```

I want the output to be all odd length stock tickers

```
['GOOGL','IBM', 'M', 'WMT']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `filter`

```
print(list(filter(lambda x: len(x) % 2 == 1, list1)))
```

With `list comprehension`

```
print([i for i in list1 if len(i)%2==1])
```

Output:

```
['GOOGL', 'IBM', 'M', 'WMT']
```